# OCPJP 6.0 upgrade

Tags: java, ocpjp

I got the OCPJP 6.0 certification 6 years back or so. I am planning to upgrade it to one of the latest Oracle certifications. Could you please recommend if I should appear for the upgrade to OCPJP 8.0/11.0 exams?

Also if there is another certification that is better, could you please make any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can upgrade your OCP 6.0 to OCP Java 11, following the  `Oracle Training and Certification` guide:

[image]

**Books:**

- [OCP Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 11 Programmer I Exam Fundamentals 1Z0-815](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1086955811)
- [OCP Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 11 Programmer I Study Guide: Exam 1Z0-815 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119584701) > *This title will be released on November 2019.*

**References:**

1. [Oracle Training and Certification guide](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/dc/ww-java-cert-guide-java-se11.pdf)
2. [Upgrade OCP Java 6, 7 & 8 to Java SE 11 Developer](https://education.oracle.com/en/upgrade-ocp-java-6-7-8-to-java-se-11-developer/pexam_1Z0-817)
3. [Oracle Certified Professional: Java SE 11 Developer (Upgrade from OCP Java 6, 7 & 8)](https://education.oracle.com/en/products/trackp_817)
4. [Pass Java 1Z0-817 Certification](https://enthuware.com/pass-java-1z0-817-certification-exam)
5. [Certification Overview and Sample Questions](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/img/dc/ww-java11-programmer-study-guide.pdf)
6. [How to prepare for Java OCP 11 1Z0-815](https://enthuware.com/resources/oracle-java-programmer-certification-resources/how-to-prepare-for-java-ocp-11-1z0-815)
7. [Java Programming Learning Subscription](https://education.oracle.com/java-se-programming-learning-subscription/ls_40805)

**I hope this answer helps you.** :)

Comment: Yes, we can do this. But I think it is a bit new, do you know of any good books/mock exams etc that we can use to prepare for OCPJP 11.0?

Comment: What is the difference between Java Oracle certified Associate/Programmer/Master

Comment: @Hello I updated my answer with some books that you can use to prepare for the certification.

Comment: A question though - I thought OCPJP 11 SE exam was IZO-817 code. Will the above books help for that? I could not find much info on books specific to IZO-817 online.

Comment: @Hello you are welcome. Hope that this can help. I updated the answer with more materials, like https://enthuware.com/pass-java-1z0-817-certification-exam. However, I strong recommend that you go to https://education.oracle.com and search more information about the IZO-817.

Comment: Thank you much, will do